# maven release plugin for project submodules

Tags: git, maven, tags, release-management, maven-release-plugin

I have a project in git repository - baseProject with bunch of module & submodules. .git file exists only at the baseProject.
I want to make maven-release plugin with work standard 'tag' feature.
This is the example project structure:

```
baseProject
 +-- pom.xml (baseProject:1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 !
 +-- module1 
 !     +-- pom.xml (module1:1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 !
 +-- module2
       +-- pom.xml (module2:1.0-SNAPSHOT)
       !
       !-- submodule1
            +-- pom.xml (submodule1:5.0-SNAPSHOT)
       !
       +-- submodule2
            +-- pom.xml (submodule2:2.0-SNAPSHOT)
       !
       +-- submodule3
            +-- pom.xml (submodule3:3.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

From the example found in different places, I can do this in baseProject.pom

```
<scm>
   <connection>scm:git:ssh://url-to-git.com/baseProject.git</connection>
   <url>scm:git:ssh://url-to-git.com/baseProject.git</url>
   <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://url-to-git.com/baseProject.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

But this does not work for submodule level. For example: module1 or submodule2.
I want to tag and release using mvn release:prepare & mvn release:perform

Note: These are not git submodules but only generated by maven in project.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

We just had the same issue, and we found a workaround: copy exactly the same `scm` tag to the submodule pom.

It looks like a bug in the release plugin to me. I filed an issue there: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-1137